# Question regarding a proof I thought about the friendship problem using graphs.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following 2 part problem :

1. Assume that the relation “friend” is symmetric. Show that if n ≥ 2, then in any group of n people there are two with the same number of friends in the group
2. How many different "friend" relations are there when there are n people and why?

I thought of something using graphs however i am not sure if it is correct or not . Here is what i thought :

1. Consider that we have a graph with vertices n ≥ 2 , in which n represents the people . Since the relation is symmetric and not reflexive , the maximum degree number of a vertex will be n-1 . So , if we have 2 people , or 2 n , then those people will be connected with 1 edge , which means that those 2 vertices will have the same degree , which means that there are 2 people with the same number of friends.

For the second part i did the following :

2. If we have 2 people, or 2 vertices , then we have 1 edge , hence 1 friendship . If we have 3 people , or 3 vertices , then the first person can be friends with the second person , the second with the third , and the first with the 3rd . Which means we have 3 friendships . If we keep that pattern , the total number of friendships in a group of n people is the number of edges in a complete graph , which is n(n-1)/2 .
   Can you tell me if what i did is correct ? If not can you direct me towards a correct proof ? Thank you .

Comment: I don't quite get your idea for the first point. You could use the pigeonhole principle for it, or if you want to use a more graphy approach, you could try to do it by induction on the number of vertices. I've been trying to do it that way, but I got stuck

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: the relation is "the whole situation".  It's not how many friends there might be, it's how many "situations" there can be.

For two people, there are two possibilities: they are friends or not.  So there are $2$ friend relations.

For three people, I will do it by looking at all possibilities:

- they are all friends - $1$ possibility;
- two pairs are friends, the other is not - $3$ possibilities as any one of the three pairs could be the "non-friends";
- one pair is friends, others not - $3$ possibilities, similar reason to above;
- none are friends - $1$ possibility.

Total, $8$ friend relations.  I'm doing it the long way to try and illustrate for you what the question actually means.  This is obviously going to be very difficult for more people, but there is a smarter method - see if you can think of it.